# Role management in Angularjs for showing and hide tabs

Tags: angularjs

We are using AngularJs , In our application we have around 8 roles like SUPER_ANDMIN, ADMIN,USER,RESELLER etc , 
so if user role is ADMIN , then 7 tabs show but if user role is USER , then only three tabs show , on every call we send role of user from server site.

so what is the best practice of it does we need to put `ng-if` on every tab or any better option in AngularJS
Thanks

Comment: either ng if, or have a collection of tabs in your controller and render them with an ng-repeat. I prefer the ng-repeat option to pull some of that logic out of the view and into the controller.

Comment: actually we have around 20,25 pages and on every page we have this problem so we are looking for any standard

Comment: There is no "standard" or "best practice". Only methods for you to choose from.

Comment: Okk Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

You can either make a hybrid application creating multiple SPA's that define certain portions of functionality within your application or you can have one SPA with multiple views and restricting views based on your role.

In case of the latter you can use ui-router with data attached per view. Upon authentication you can determine the role and restrict the user from viewing certain pages.

I have a small `example` on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6slTHbRK7LtuhdKlmPUH?p=preview). Note that I haven't restricted the navigation in order for you to see that viewing the corresponding pages is prohibited nor is the authentication in any way a real implementation.